# Footnote appears twice in pbox in tabularx

Tags: footnotes, tabularx

If I put a footnote inside of a pbox in a tabularx cell, then the footnote is listed twice at the bottom of the page.  The footnote counter also increases by two.

Here's a mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand{\mlines}[1]{%                                                                                
    \pbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
      \hline
      A\footnote{This footnote appears once.}           & B \\ \hline
      \mlines{line1\\line2\footnote{this footnote appears twice.}\\line3} & D\footnote{single again.} \\\
  \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

For what it's worth, I'm not wedded to using a pbox -- I chose it to allow control of line breaks in a table cell.  My use case:  I have a landscape table, with 11 columns and many rows (full page).  I'd like to have footnotes (or table notes) on text in table cells, as well as the header.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just remove the `\mlines` command, it serves no purpose to have a fixed width tabular which prevents automatic line breaks in an X column which is variable width and allows multiple lines already.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The MWE doesn't capture my full use case.  I need to insert line breaks at specific locations within the cell (different from automatic wrapping of text).  I've updated the MWE to show line breaks in a cell.  Do you know how to resolve the footnote issue?

Comment: but `X` is a multi-line cell type anyway, so you can just use `\newline` in the text

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant.  Yes, your suggestion works for me -- thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments